# Bootstrap dropdown toggle with button group does not work in nav-bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on MVC 5 and using Bootstrap for my front end design. I have CSHTML layout pages in my shared folder. All the layouts contain a nav-bar that has several options in it. However, the btn-group within the `<form class="navbar-form navbar-right"></form>` does not show the dropdown menu. Here is the code snippet:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @Session["emp_main_first"] <span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>

                 <!-- dropdown menu items-->
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit profile</a></li>
                     <li><a href="../EmployeeRegister/LogOut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Log out</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

What is that I am missing out? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: im confused as I tested the code shown here and the dropdown is displayed  

as shown here:
http://www.bootply.com/HyPzXN0L1I

Comment: thanks @jamie. I narrowed down the issue. The control is working in all the other layouts except one. I am using the same navbar without making any changes to it, but surprisingly, the dropdown does not appear when I click on the button. What possibly can be the issue here?

Comment: is it possible for you to create bootply example so i can see the full page as the code you have shown here seems to be working when i test it

Comment: the catch is if I use the code in any other page or say a fiddle, it seems to work perfectly. Its not working only when m using it in that one particular page. could it be any issues with the bootstrap references?

Comment: are you using the latest bootstrap resources ?

Comment: yup. m using bootstrap 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code same as it is, it should work in your case.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @Session["emp_main_first"] <span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <!-- dropdown menu items-->
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit profile</a></li>
                     <li><a href="../EmployeeRegister/LogOut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Log out</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a ton Faisal. That fixed the problem. But m still wondering what was the actual error that was causing this issue! :/

Comment: What i think there was a confliction, you were using old jquery library that conflict with bootstrap javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<a></a>` instead of `<button></button>`and apply css.

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
</div>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: For whatever reason this fixed my problem when using a btn-group inside of a panel-footer

Answer (score 0):

Give dropdown menu an ID and then call it from data-target
So,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#dropdown">
```

Then, call it with an ID from

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdown">
```

This, looks for an ID on what to toggle (hence, menus to show).